# How to set default title for a custom spinner?

Tags: android, header, spinner, default, title

I have a spinner with some values from SQLite database. When I started the activity I want to show the title of the spinner "--Select Category--" not the data in adapter. How can I do this?

```
String[] data = ndbHandler.getAllLabels();

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);


        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner

        spinCat.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is the ndbHandler database class

```
public String[] getAllLabels(){
    Cursor cr=this.sDB.query(TABLE_LABELS, new String[] {KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(cr.getCount() >0)
    {
        String[] str = new String[cr.getCount()];
        int i = 0;


        while (cr.moveToNext())
        {
             str[i] = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME));
             i++;
         }
    return str;

}


    else
    {
        return new String[]{};
    }
```

Comment: just Added this value from the first potition of Array

Comment: where is code that u r gating array

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar - Question edited with code.. Please check

Comment: Reshmin check  may Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add "Select Category" string at the first location in your string array or arraylist. before setting it to spinner.

```
String[] SpinnerItem=new String[]{"Select Category","First","Second","Third"};
```

For ArrayList-

```
ArrayList<String> mArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

mArrayList=getDataFromSqlite();// retrieve your data first.
mArrayList.add(0,"Select Category");
```

Your database code -

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllLabels(){
ArrayList<String> mArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();

    Cursor c=this.sDB.query(TABLE_LABELS, new String[] {KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);

if(c != null){
            if (c.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                     mArrayList.add(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));
                }while(c.moveToNext());
            }
        }

    return mArrayList;

}
```

Setting spinner -

```
ArrayList<String> data = ndbHandler.getAllLabels();
data.add(0,"Select Category");

adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);


        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner

        spinCat.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This is not a custom array. Getting values from SQLite database and inserting into the spinner with arrayadapter. please check my question I have edited with my code.

Comment: Yes. You can add filed to first position after getting value from database.Use ArrayList instead of array.So that you can add string at first position after getting all values.

Comment: If there are no items in database the spinner will be blank. So I want to show "-Select category-" as a title to default.

Comment: Yes. See my updated code.It will definitely work in your case.I am using the same condition in my project

Comment: Just add your data in arraylist instead of array.

Comment: When changing the array into arraylist what changes wil be there in the ndbHandler database class. Please edit my question with arraylist

Comment: Yes.. Helped your answer and @Naveen Tamrakar answer.. Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 0):

Here am trying to add `Select Category` as first element in a String array with your labels

```
String[] allLables = ndbHandler.getAllLabels();
String[] data = new String[allLables.length + 1];
data[0] = "Select Category";
System.arraycopy(allLabels, 0, data, 1, allLabels.length);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data );
            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            // attaching data adapter to spinner
spinCat.setAdapter(adapter);
```

OR you can use

```
String[] data = ndbHandler.getAllLabels();
ArrayList<String> list =new ArrayList<String>( Arrays.asList( data ) );
list.add(0, "Select Category");
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list );
                        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        // attaching data adapter to spinner
spinCat.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: @jenuine- I have tried this but I am getting unsupportedOperationException in line  list.add(0, "Select Category"); why?

Comment: can you tell me the jdk version

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
String[] allLabels = ndbHandler.getAllLabels();
String[] data = new String[allLables.length + 1];
data[0] = "--Select Category--";
System.arraycopy(allLabels, 0, data, 1, allLabels.leng);
```

Then pass the data[] to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

```
this in done in your database class

public ArrayList<String> arrayList getAllLabels()
{
    Cursor cr=this.sDB.query(TABLE_LABELS, new String[] {KEY_NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> temparrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    temparrayList.add("--Select Category--");

     if (cr.moveToFirst()) 
       {
      do
             {
          temparrayList.add(cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME)));    
             }
              while (cursor.moveToNext());
       }
    return temparrayList;
}

 this is done in your Activity

ArrayList<String> data= ndbHandler.getAllLabels();
dapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, data);
// Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// attaching data adapter to spinner
spinCat.setAdapter(adapter);
```